# Show that this piecewise function is differentiable at $0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have shown (from first principles) that the Cauchy-Riemann equations for the following function are satisfied at $z=0$. But to properly prove differentiability at $z=0$, what should I do next? Do I go on to show that the four partial derivatives are continuous at $0$ (if so, please show how)?

$$f(z)=\cases{\frac{x^4-6x^2y^2+y^4}{x^2+y^2} +i\frac{4xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2},& $z\ne0$\cr 0, &$z=0$}$$

Answer (score 2):

For differentiability at $z=0$, in addition to Cauchy-Riemann, the two functions $u,v$ in $f(z)=u+iv$ must be shown to be *real differentiable*, which is a stronger requirement than that the partials exist. However it is not necessary that the partials be continuous at $0$. Reference:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations

As I recall "real differentiable" has to do with the existence of a good tangent plane approximation, which I believe in your example is the plane $w=0$ if the variable $w$ is used as output name for say the function $u(x,y)$.

It seems interesting to note that, if $z=x+iy$, then your map is precisely
$$f(z)=\frac{z^4}{z \bar{z}}.$$ I vaguely recall there was a rule of thumb: holomorphic iff when written in $z,\bar{z}$ notation no dependence on $\bar{z}$. I guess that was referring to holomorphic on open sets, and your example only satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equations at the single point $z=0$, at least that's the only obvious place.

ADDED: Just to clear up a distinction: even in the one variable case, a function $f(x)$ can be "real differentiable" at $x=0$ without its derivative being continuous there. Example $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ for nonzero $x$, and $f(0)=0$. To check $f'(0)=0$ one needs to use the definition and finds $[f(0+h)-f(0)]/h=h \sin(1/h)$ with limit zero as $h \to 0$. However $f'(x)=2x \sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$ is not continuous at $x=0$ since the $x \sin(1/x)$ term becomes negligible while $\cos(1/x)$ oscillates in $[-1,1].$

What the Wikipedia article (and another text I consulted) says is that, in order that $f(z)$ be differentiable at $z_0$, one needs the Cauchy Riemann equations (which of course assumes the *existence* of the four partials), along with something more. That something more is in general the existence of the real derivatives of $u,v$ as functions of two variables at the point $z_0$, which is stronger than that the partials merely exist. One can avoid reference to the real differentiability of $u,v$ by simply assuming their partial derivatives are continuous at $z_0$, but this is a stronger assumption than is necessary for $f'(z_0)$ to exist. But to emphasize: one cannot get by just by checking the Cauchy Riemann equations hold -- one needs also real differentiability of $u,v$ or continuity of the four partials which implies the required real differentiability.

Comment: You're totally messing with what I thought I knew. I have just consulted several texts and notes (all for first courses in complex analysis), and all just give that the partials being continuous at 0 is sufficient for differentiability (if the C-R eqns are satisfied, of course). I wonder why what you cited from Wikipedia is not more commonly invoked or given in textbooks.

Comment: I just consulted Marsden and Hoffman's "Basic Complex Analysis" (3rd ed). Their version [pp65-66] also notes the need for differentiability in the real sense. They also remark that *if* $u,v$ happen to be continuous at the given particular point, then real differentiability follows from that, and in that case all one needs is Cauchy Riemann to get $f'(z_0)$ exists. And in the remarks they note that real differentiability is actually a weaker assumption than continuity of partials at $z_0.$ Maybe the continuity of partials is being assumed in the other texts?

Comment: Did you just contradict your original claim (and what is on wikipedia)? Is the real differentiability a weaker or stronger assumption than the continuity of the partials? If weaker, then all the references I'm consulting are good then, since they give the stronger (latter) requirement. In any case, I'm not saying either is wrong, since both requirements can stand alongside.

Comment: See part inserted after "ADDED" in my answer about this strong/weak issue... to involved for a quick response here.